# Multivariate integration of a compicated expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have an expression in multiple variables that is something like

```
4.85746*10^-7 Cos[ϕ] (1 + 
   1/2 (Abs[(-1.5782 Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
          1.329 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.5782 Sqrt[
           1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
          1.329 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2 + 
      Abs[(1.329 Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] - 
          1.5782 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.329 Sqrt[
           1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
          1.5782 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2) Cos[
     2 ArcSin[
       z Sin[ϕ]]] - ((1 + 
        1/2 (-Abs[(-1.5782 Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
                1.329 Sqrt[
                 1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.5782 Sqrt[
                 1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
                1.329 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2 - 
           Abs[(1.329 Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] - 
               1.5782 Sqrt[
                1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.329 Sqrt[
                1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
               1.5782 Sqrt[
                1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2))^2 (Cos[
         2 ArcSin[0.842099 z Sin[ϕ]] - 
          2 ArcSin[z Sin[ϕ]]] + 
        1/2 (Abs[(-1.5782 Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
               1.329 Sqrt[
                1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.5782 Sqrt[
                1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
               1.329 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2 + 
           Abs[(1.329 Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] - 
               1.5782 Sqrt[
                1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.329 Sqrt[
                1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
               1.5782 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2) Cos[
          2 ArcSin[z Sin[ϕ]]]))/(1 + 
      1/4 (Abs[(-1.5782 Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
             1.329 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.5782 Sqrt[
              1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
             1.329 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2 + 
         Abs[(1.329 Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] - 
             1.5782 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.329 Sqrt[
              1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
             1.5782 Sqrt[
              1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2)^2 + (Abs[(-1.5782 \
Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
             1.329 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.5782 Sqrt[
              1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
             1.329 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2 + 
         Abs[(1.329 Sqrt[1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] - 
             1.5782 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])/(1.329 Sqrt[
              1 - z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2] + 
             1.5782 Sqrt[1 - 0.70913 z^2 Sin[ϕ]^2])]^2) Cos[
        2 ArcSin[0.842099 z Sin[ϕ]]]))
```

I want to integrate this expression first w.r.t. ϕ with limits 0 to 7 π/18 and then indefinite integral `Integrate[F, z]` w.r.t `z`. I tried it in many ways, but it is very difficult for me to solve this integral. Can anyone help to find out the solution of this integral. I would be highly obliged.

Comment: I highly doubt you can find an indefinite integral here. Such complicated functions are usually best solved numerically.

Comment: Are you certain that you need a symbolic result?  What do you want to use it for?

Comment: after this integral i want to plot graph between thisfunction and z.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand cannot be solved when $|z|\rightarrow1$
Therefore, let's integrate the function on a possible domain, numerically.

```
zdat=Table[NIntegrate[f, {Phi, 0, 7 Pi/18}, {z, 0, i}], {i, -0.95, 0.95, 0.1}];
```

This gives us a list of values, from which we can approximate a function for this part of the domain for `z`.
Plotting this list gives us:

```
lp = ListPlot[data = Transpose[{Table[i, {i, -0.95, 0.95, 0.1}], zdat}]]
```

[image]

We can use this to formulate an approximate function for `z`.
The function appears to be odd, and includes the point `{0,0}`, and we can try an odd polynomial.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a z + b z^3, {a, b}, z]//Normal
```

> 1.2737*10^-8 z + 8.36705*10^-9 z^3

```
Show[Plot[nlm, {z, -0.95, 0.95}, PlotStyle -> Red], lp]
```

[image]

Adding a fifth order term barely changes the plot.

```
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, a z + b z^3 + c z^5, {a, b, c}, z] // 
  Normal

Plot[{nlm, nlm2}, {z, -0.95, 0.95}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}}]
```

[image]

Therefore the third order polynomial appears to approximate the function you seek quite well.

$$1.2737\times 10^{-8} z + 8.36705\times 10^{-9} z^3$$

When we extend the domain, the integrand becomes highly oscillatory, the errors in the numerical integration become quite large.

[image]

At this point, the function becomes rather more complicated, the function is then better approximated with an interpolating function:

```
zdat = Table[NIntegrate[f, {\[Phi], 0, 7 Pi/18}, {z, 0, i}, 
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive",MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}], {i, -2.01, 2.01, 0.1}];

data = Re[zdat];
data = Transpose[{Table[i, {i, -2.01, 2.01, 0.1}], data}];
ip = Interpolation[data];
Show[Plot[ip[z], {z, -2.01`, 1.9900000000000002`}, PlotStyle -> Red],ListPlot[data]]
```

[image]

Comment: but i want to plot in -2 to 2 range.Is their any possible solution for that .

Comment: @AnitaMaheshwari I've extended my answer.

Comment: I am running these command again and again but it is showing me some error like its not a valid command for z and so,

Comment: I have one more question this is the plot only for phi integral.their is any possiblity to integrate this function w.r.t z??

Comment: whatever you did may be its correct but the nature of the curve is not correct because the way you did in this is you are integrating w.r.t particular value every time that's why it will give you the nature of curve same as after integrating phi if you plot after phi integration is same as this curve.That's why i want separate indefinite integral of z.

Comment: @AnitaMaheshwari Have you see [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)?  Or is it something else?  (Forgive me, but I do not think I understand your comment.)  What Feyre and I have done is to give you an `InterpolatingFunction`, each in our own way, that approximates $F(z) = \int_0^z \int_{0}^{7 \pi/18} f(\zeta, \phi)\;d\phi \; d\zeta$.  The general indefinite integral is just this $F(z)$ plus a constant, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: its oky but somehow your code is helpfull for me thanku so much

Comment: if I just want to integrate phi not z then how I will change this command?

Comment: Which version of mathematica are you using to do this simulation??In your version it also show some error or not?its very helpful for me if you can send me that mathematica file by email if you can.

Comment: @AnitaMaheshwari
Unfortunately you cannot just integrate `Phi`, as numerical integration cannot be done while there's another symbolic variable there.
Everything I did is there. The errors are there because it warns about potential errors in the numerical integration. This gives the error estimate in the value it calculates, for instance for i=1.95: `NIntegrate obtained 4.84825*10^-9+1.53766*10^-27 I and 1.67537*10^-13 for the error`. So, the accuracy is to greater than 0.35% difference.

Comment: Can I integrate w.r.t z for a particular phi value??

Comment: @AnitaMaheshwari The methods here provide integral function for `z` for the specific domain of `phi` you specified, is that not what you're asking for now?

Comment: this method is for specific domain of phi but i am asking about for one particular value say phi = pi/3 and then integrate w.r.t. z?

Comment: @AnitaMaheshwari You can run `Table[NIntegrate[f /. {\[Phi] -> \[Pi]/3}, {z, i, 0}]`

Comment: if their is only integral in phi domain and plotting w.r.t z.(mean let f is your function of phi and z,now i just want to integartef w.r.t. to phi in 0 to 7*pi/18 domain and then plot w.r.t z) can we do like pull out z command and then plot?

Comment: @AnitaMaheshwari No. Because the function is too complicated to integrate symbolically, and if you want to integrate it w.r.t `phi` numerically, then you need to integrate `z` numerically too. I'm sorry, but what you're asking is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

One can use `NDSolve` to construct a particular "indefinite" integral, e.g.,
$$f(z) = \int_0^z f'(ζ) \; dζ$$

First define `integrand` to be the OP's expression.  The the following computes its integral.

```
Clear[df];
df[z0_?NumericQ] := 
  df[z0] = NIntegrate[integrand /. z -> z0, {ϕ, 0, 7 Pi/18}, 
    Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}, 
    MaxRecursion -> 20];
{fsol} = NDSolve[{f'[z] == df[z], f[0] == 0}, 
    f, {z, -2., 2.}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {1.89007, Null}  *)
```

The function is an [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) that can be obtained with `f /. fsol` or plotted with `f[z] /. fsol`.  See the documentation for [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) for more examples.

```
Plot[f[z] /. fsol, {z, -2., 2.}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: when I run this integral in my mathematica 10.0 it showed me many error .Can you please tell me what should i do to remove all these error?

Comment: @AnitaMaheshwari Did you define `integrand` to be your integrand?

Comment: whatever you did may be its correct but the nature of the curve is not correct because the way you did in this is you are integrating w.r.t particular value every time that's why it will give you the nature of curve same as after integrating phi if you plot after phi integration is same as this curve.That's why i want separate indefinite integral of z.

Comment: @AnitaMaheshwari Like I said from the get-go, integrating this function symbolically is impossible. An interpolating function, is as good as it gets.

Comment: can you please explain your code briefly because i tried that thing in mathematica 10 and i found nothing.Its a humble request if you can do this??taking main function to f.